# Extracting Date from a string (URL)

Tags: r, gsub

I am trying to extract dates from 40k URLs.
URLs are like this :

```
1) ht-p://mashable.com/2014/09/19/shonda-rhimes-new-york-times/
2) http://mashable.com-2014/11/02/friendly-robbers-snl-sketch/
```

I am using this :

```
ymd(as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", df$URL)))
```

which worked fine with 1 or 2 records but with 40k records it gives me

> Warning message: 
>   4714 failed to parse. Its giving NAs for these 4714 values.

Am I missing something?

Comment: is there any  num exits on the url other than date..

Comment: try `ymd(as.numeric(gsub(".*/(\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2})/.*", "\\1", df$URL)))`

Comment: Your primary solution worked just fine even with 40k size vector of urls.
`urls = rep(c("ht-p://mashable.com/2014/09/19/shonda-rhimes-new-     york-times/", "http://mashable.com-2014/11/02/friendly-robbers-snl-sketch/"), 20000)`
`dates = ymd(as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", urls)))`

Answer (score 3):

Using `str_extract` form `stringr` package :

```
library(stringr)
as.Date(str_extract(txts,"[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}"),"%Y/%m/%d")
## [1] "2014-09-19" "2014-11-02"
```

where `txts` is :

```
txts <- c("ht-p://mashable.com/2014/09/19/shonda-rhimes-new-york-times/",
"http://mashable.com-2014/11/02/friendly-robbers-snl-sketch/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(string = df$URL,pattern = "[[:digit:]]+"),function(t) paste0(tail(t,n = 3),collapse = "/"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple ways using the `stringi` underpinnings of `stringr` directly:

```
library(lubridate)
library(stringi)
library(magrittr)

c("ht-p://mashable.com/2014/09/19/shonda-rhimes-new-york-times/",
  "http://mashable.com-2014/11/02/friendly-robbers-snl-sketch/") -> URLs

URLs %>% 
  stri_extract_all_regex("([[:digit:]]{4}/[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2})", simplify=TRUE) %>% 
  ymd(.[,1])


URLs %>% 
  stri_match_all_regex("([[:digit:]]{4}/[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2})") %>% 
  lapply("[", 2) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  ymd()
```